# Random query is hitting PostgreSQL RDS instance

Tags: django, postgresql, bots, amazon-rds

We have a django application hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, which is using PostgreSQL RDS as a database.

Since yesterday, we found that our RDS storage shows full-storage message.

When we checked the logs are filling up and taking most of the space.

The logs shows some random query is hitting the DB and causing error.

```
2017-10-30 06:59:59 UTC:172.31.0.218(48038):MyPostgreSQLDB@ebdb:[16817]:STATEMENT: INSERT INTO "auth_user" ("password", "last_login", "is_superuser", "username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "is_staff", "is_active", "date_joined") 
VALUES ('pbkdf2_sha256$30000$L21goli52Bdt$CrFNDOGuwszHC3wkKvoVee1O8ey/V/NdMt9CaG53mCk=', NULL, false, 'dk12345678910111213141516171819202122232425', 'd', 'K', '', false, true, '2017-10-30T06:59:59.550627+00:00'::timestamptz) RETURNING "auth_user"."id"
2017-10-30 07:00:00 UTC:172.31.6.238(47206):MyPostgreSQLDB@ebdb:[22437]:ERROR: value too long for type character varying(150)
2017-10-30 07:00:00 UTC:172.31.6.238(47206):MyPostgreSQLDB@ebdb:[22437]:STATEMENT: INSERT INTO "auth_user" ("password", "last_login", "is_superuser", "username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "is_staff", "is_active", "date_joined") 
VALUES ('pbkdf2_sha256$30000$rtHpPn996XzO$H2RS/H5RYHC12MxjnRIRK1St21VQS8/6Bd/Hnc3H0Jc=', NULL, false, 'deepak kumar k12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031', 'Deepak Kumar ', 'k', '', false, true, '2017-10-30T06:59:58.751020+00:00'::timestamptz) RETURNING "auth_user"."id"
2017-10-30 07:00:00 UTC:172.31.26.180(52740):MyPostgreSQLDB@ebdb:[23882]:ERROR: value too long for type character varying(150)
2017-10-30 07:00:00 UTC:172.31.26.180(52740):MyPostgreSQLDB@ebdb:[23882]:STATEMENT: INSERT INTO "auth_user" ("password", "last_login", "is_superuser", "username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "is_staff", "is_active", "date_joined") 
VALUES ('pbkdf2_sha256$30000$Ve4JkxutDfyC$lB9A+bzEvQSJYamlhXscU/cWfDHtMSHaMU45kKcyxsM=', NULL, false, 'ashokkumar1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435', 'ASHOK', 'Kumar', '', false, true, '2017-10-30T07:00:00.208427+00:00'::timestamptz) RETURNING "auth_user"."id"
2017-10-30 07:00:00 UTC:172.31.26.180(52938):MyPostgreSQLDB@ebdb:[26159]:ERROR: value too long for type character varying(150)
```

We are not able to trace who is hitting this random query?

How can we locate the culprit application or who is trying to do this and block?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope you have changed the DB credentials before posting this question and locked down the DB. Are these Ip's `172.31.0.218` and `172.31.26.180` and `172.31.6.238` your ec2 instance ips?

Comment: @MadhukarMohanraju Yes, I have changed the DB credentials, but what do you mean by locking down the DB? Regarding IPs: We are using Elastic Beanstalk, looks like these are private IPs of the EC2 instances launched by that environment. The IP range is kinda like that `172.31.*.*`